# Загрузка UINavigatorController по нажатию на кнопку

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Помогите, пожалуйста, реализовать загрузку `UINavigatorController` по нажатию на кнопку. Все смог сделать, только `UINavigatorController` загружается сразу. А мне надо, чтобы сначала было окно с кнопкой и при нажатии на кнопку только потом открывался `UINavigatorController`.

Comment: Он и должен загружаться сразу, а при нажатии на кнопку загружать в него соответствующее UIView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что конкретно вас смущает? Вы можете просто скрыть навигейшн бар для первого контроллера, просто вставть в - `(void)viewDidLoad` строку

```
  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

а при пуше с следующего контроллера соответственно NO, ну и вернуть все как было при возвращении на первый контроллер. Это будет правильно. Если очень хочется генерить контроллер именно по нажатию на кнопку, то могу написать код, но это не совсем верно и удобно, на самом деле.

Comment: Мне надо чтобы первое окно было с кнопкой и нажатие на кнопку открывало UINavigatorController со списком.Вот как мне сделать переход при нажатии на кнопку к списку?Удалить с первой страницы UINavigatorController всё и добавить кнопку?

Comment: Как написал товарисч aknew hidden=yes, а когда перейдете в detailviewcontroller hidden=no. Переход [self.navigationController pushViewController:(имявашеговьюконтроллера) animated:YES];